# Unplugged wire in Dell Vostro 1510 laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-vostro

So I was opening my laptop to replace the hard drive and I noticed something very strange.
There was a loose wire. Do I need to be worried about this?

I posted earlier on [Stackexchance electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27147/unplugged-wire-in-dell-vostro-1510-laptop), but they closed the question saying it was the wrong forum.
However, I got some info that this may have to do with my wireless card. I actually had been having strange problems with my wireless, such as it not working until I flipped on and off the physical wireless switch on the computer. However, when I upgraded to Windows 7 from Windows Vista, these problems disappeared.

Attached are some images. Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice pics by the way.

Comment: I agree with @Moab, nice pics. I embedded them for you.

Answer (score 6):

Some wireless cards have a third antenna connection.  This appears to be for that.  The flat connector should be the same as the ones on the Wireless card in your image.  Some use this for a Bluetooth card or something like a 3G or similar card. It just may be for an option that is not installed on your particular laptop.

Comment: Since the bare connector is loose, I'd make sure to at least cover the exposed metal with electrical tape prior to sealing up the system.

Comment: Cool, I guess I don't need to worry about it then. Thanks!