# An unconnected line found inside my Lenovo T400

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unplugged wire in Dell Vostro 1510 laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/395885/unplugged-wire-in-dell-vostro-1510-laptop)

I have experienced dropping wireless connection problem with my Lenovo T400  with both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. I am trying to examine the inside of my laptop, to see if it is because the wireless adaptor has become loosely fitted in. Following are two front views of the inside of my laptop (the second one is a little closer than the first):

[image]
Closer look:
[image]

I notice there is a white line wearing a black hat on one end, and
    this end is not connected to any place. (This line is singled out by a pair of tweezers in the second picture)

1. I wonder  what this line
   for, and where it should connect to?
2. Is it the reason that my wireless connection is often dropped?

   If not, where might be the problem?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a spare antenna for a 3x3 WLAN card. It shouldn't be causing the problems you're experiencing, because, as you can see, it's not actually connected to anything.

Check that the two antenna leads connected to your WLAN card (black and grey) are seated properly.

Comment: Thanks! Is my WLAN card the green chip with white label covered most of its front, shown in the top right corners of both pictures?

Comment: @Tim Yes, that's the one. The model is most likely Intel WiFi Link 5100, or 5150 if you also have WiMAX support.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is Intel WiFi Link 5100, with Model 512AN_MMW. The two lines black and grey are connected to my WLAN card tight. What else physical connections/... might cause the problem and I can check while the inside is being open now?